# xhtml form not dropping values after submit

Tags: jquery

I have a problem with submitting values. After saving all in base all values stay on their places when try to create new project. What i need to add? If it's really, i'd want not to create reset button.

```
<h:body>
    <f:view>

    <div align="center"> 
    <h3>Новый проект</h3>
    </div>
    <table width="100%" height="100%" >
      <h:form id="form">  
          <p:growl id="growl" class="ui-growl"  showDetail="false"  sticky="false" life="10000"/>
        <tr>
            <td>
      <h:panelGrid columns="2" styleClass="h_pgrid-style">  

        <h:outputLabel for="title" value="Название: " styleClass="el-style"/>  
         <p:inputTextarea id="title"  style="height:22px; width:400px; overflow-y:scroll ;" 
                                   required="true" styleClass="ell-style" value="#{projectBean.prTitle}">
            <p:ajax event="change" process="title" partialSubmit="true"  />
         </p:inputTextarea>                       

        <h:outputLabel for="description" value="Описание: "  styleClass="el-style"/>  
        <p:inputTextarea id="description"  style="height:180px; width:400px; overflow-y:scroll ;"    
                         styleClass="ell-style" required="true" value="#{projectBean.prDesctiption}"> 
            <p:ajax event="change" process="description" partialSubmit="true"  />
        </p:inputTextarea>

        </h:panelGrid></td>

          <td>
         <h:panelGrid columns="2"   styleClass="hp_pgrid-style">  

        <h:outputLabel for="period" value="Срок выполнения: " style="width:12px"   styleClass="el-style"/>  

        <p:calendar  id="period" size="15" required="true" value="#{projectBean.prDate}" >

            <p:ajax event="dateSelect" process="period" partialSubmit="true"  /> 

        </p:calendar>

        <h:outputLabel for="sum" value="Бюджет (руб.): "  styleClass="el-style"/>      
        <p:inputText id="sum" size="15"  required="true" value="#{projectBean.prBudget}">
            <p:ajax event="change" process="sum" partialSubmit="true"  />
        </p:inputText>

        <h:outputLabel for="moderator" value="Модератор: "  styleClass="el-style"/> 
        <h:panelGroup style="display:block; text-align:left">          
            <p:selectOneMenu id="moderator" value="#{projectBean.prMod}"  style="width:175px"                        
                         styleClass="el-style">
            <p:ajax event="change" process="moderator" partialSubmit="true"  /> 
             <f:selectItem itemLabel="-- Выберите ФИО -- " noSelectionOption="true"/>
             <f:selectItems value="#{moderatorBean.moderatorsList}"  var="selectedModerator" itemValue="#{selectedModerator.id}" 
                            itemLabel="#{selectedModerator.modFamily} #{selectedModerator.modFirstName} #{selectedModerator.modSecName}"/> 
         </p:selectOneMenu>
       </h:panelGroup>

        <h:outputLabel for="status" value="Статус: "  styleClass="el-style"/>  
       <h:panelGroup style="display:block; text-align:left"> 
           <p:selectOneMenu id="status" required="true" value="#{projectBean.prStatus}" 
                         label="Статус" style="width:175px" immediate="true">  
               <p:ajax event="change" process="status" partialSubmit="true"  /> 
            <f:selectItem itemLabel=" " itemValue="#{null}"  />
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="невидим" itemValue="невидим" />
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="опубликован" itemValue="опубликован" />
        </p:selectOneMenu>
       </h:panelGroup>  

        <f:facet name="footer">    
            <h:panelGroup style="display:block; text-align:center">
               <p:commandButton id="submit" type="submit" value="Создать" styleClass="elp-style"   
                                 process="@this" action="#{projectBean.CreateNewProjectSubmit(clientBean.clientId)}" 
                                 update="growl"  />


            </h:panelGroup>

        </f:facet>          

        </h:panelGrid>  

        </td>           

        </tr>
       </h:form>    
      </table> 

        </f:view>
</h:body>
```

Comment: resetting the model would do, i guess.

Comment: you mean just to refresh it?